# What is the meaning of the CascadeType.ALL for a @ManyToOne JPA association

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, cascade, many-to-one

I think I misunderstood the meaning of cascading in the context of a `@ManyToOne` relationship.

The case:

```
public class User {

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   protected Set<Address> userAddresses;

}

public class Address {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   protected User addressOwner;

}
```

What is the meaning of the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`? For example, if I delete a certain address from the database, how does the fact that I added the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` affect my data (the `User`, I guess)?

Answer (score 478, accepted):

The meaning of `CascadeType.ALL` is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all `EntityManager` operations (`PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH`) to the relating entities.

It seems in your case to be a bad idea, as removing an `Address` would lead to removing the related `User`. As a user can have multiple addresses, the other addresses would become orphans. However the inverse case (annotating the `User`) would make sense - if an address belongs to a single user only, it is safe to propagate the removal of all addresses belonging to a user if this user is deleted.

BTW: you may want to add a `mappedBy="addressOwner"` attribute to your `User` to signal to the persistence provider that the join column should be in the ADDRESS table.

Comment: It could be good to have CascadeType.ALL on @OneToMany side though.

Answer (score 132):

You shouldn't use `CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToOne` since entity state transitions should propagate from parent entities to child ones, not the other way around.

The `@ManyToOne` is on the child side of the association as it maps the underlying Foreign Key column.

Therefore, you should move the `CascadeType.ALL` from the `@ManyToOne` association to the `@OneToMany` side, which should also use the `mappedBy` attribute since it's the most efficient one-to-many table relationship mapping.

Answer (score 61):

[See here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_cascade) for an example from the OpenJPA docs. `CascadeType.ALL` means it will do all actions.

Quote:

> CascadeType.PERSIST: When persisting an entity, also persist the entities held in its fields. We suggest a liberal application of this cascade rule, because if the EntityManager finds a field that references a new entity during the flush, and the field does not use CascadeType.PERSIST, it is an error.
>
> CascadeType.REMOVE: When deleting an entity, it also deletes the entities held in this field.
>
> CascadeType.REFRESH: When refreshing an entity, also refresh the entities held in this field.
>
> CascadeType.MERGE: When merging entity state, also merge the entities held in this field.

Sebastian

Comment: New in JPA, this information is usefull but what about Detach here?

Comment: In CascadeType.DETACH, when detaching an entity, em also detach the entities held by parent entity.

Answer (score 23):

[From the EJB3.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/ejb-3_0-fr-spec-persistence.pdf):

> Use of the cascade annotation element may be used to propagate the
> effect of an operation to associated entities. The cascade
> functionality is most typically used in parent-child relationships.
>
> If X is a managed entity, the remove operation causes it to become
> removed. The remove operation is cascaded to entities referenced by X,
> if the relationships from X to these other entities is annotated with
> the cascade=REMOVE or cascade=ALL annotation element value.

So in a nutshell, entity relationships defined with `CascadeType.All` will ensure that all persistence events such as persist, refresh, merge and remove that occur on the parent, will be passed to the child. Defining other `CascadeType` options provides the developer with a more granular level of control over how the entity association handles persistence.

For example if I had an object Book that contained a List of pages and I add a page object within this list.  If the `@OneToMany` annotation defining the association between Book and Page is marked as `CascadeType.All`, persisting the Book would result in the Page also being persisted to the database.

Answer (score 16):

In JPA 2.0 if you want to delete an address if you removed it from a User entity you can add `orphanRemoval=true` (instead of `CascadeType.REMOVE`) to your `@OneToMany`.

More explanation between `orphanRemoval=true` and `CascadeType.REMOVE` is [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete#Orphan_Removal).

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to delete the address assigned to the user and not to affect on User entity class you should try something like that:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "addressOwner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   protected Set<Address> userAddresses = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity 
public class Addresses {
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH) @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
   protected User addressOwner;
}
```

This way you dont need to worry about using fetch in annotations. But remember when deleting the User you will also delete connected address to user object.