# Facing problems persisting entities using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel

I have an Entity, Request

```
class Request {
    ---------
    ---------
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RequestStatusType
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="STATUS", nullable=false)
    private RequestStatusType requestStatusType;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RequestType
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_TYPE_ID")
    private RequestType requestType;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RequestDevice
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="request", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<RequestDevice> requestDevices;
    --------
    --------
}
```

And here is RequestStatusType,

```
class RequestStatusType{
    --------
    --------
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Request
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="requestStatusType")
    private List<Request> requests;
    --------
    --------
}
```

And here is RequestType,

```
class RequestType{
    -------
    -------
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Request
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="requestType",cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Request> requests;
    -------
    -------
}
```

And here is my RequestDevice,

```
class RequestDevice{
    --------
    --------
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DeviceStatusType
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="STATUS", nullable=false)
    private DeviceStatusType deviceStatusType;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PinType
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PIN_TYPE_ID")
    private PinType pinType;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Request
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REQUEST_ID")
    private Request request;

    --------
    --------
}
```

And here is DeviceStatusType

```
class DeviceStatusType{
    -------
    -------
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RequestDevice
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="deviceStatusType")
    private List<RequestDevice> requestDevices;
    -------
    -------
}
```

And here is my PinType

```
class PinType{
    -------
    -------
    //bi-directional many-to-one association to RequestDevice
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pinType")
    private List<RequestDevice> requestDevices;
    -------
    -------
}
```

With all the entities ready, when i do persist in pure java it works fine

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.persist(request);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

But when i do it in camel, like below

```
.to("jpa:com.labs.model.Request?usePersist=true&flushOnSend=true")
```

It is giving me an error

```
Encountered unmanaged object "com.labs.model.DeviceStatusType-1" in life cycle state  unmanaged while cascading persistence via field "com.labs.model.RequestDevice.deviceStatusType" during flush.  However, this field does not allow cascade persist. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects.
Suggested actions: a) Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), 
 b) enable cascade-persist globally, 
 c) manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. 
 d) if the reference belongs to another context, allow reference to it by setting StoreContext.setAllowReferenceToSiblingContext().
```

Can someone please explain where i am doing wrong. Your help greatly appreciated.

**Edit :**
I only want to persist Request and RequestDevice. I already have the data for RequestStatusType,RequestType,DeviceStatusType,PinType. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Can someone from camel community, help me with this...

Answer (score 1):

Check the status

```
persistence via field "com.labs.model.RequestDevice.deviceStatusType" during flush 
.....
Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL.
```

What is your purpose? Would like to persist `RequestDevice` together with `DeviceStatusType`? If so, you have to use [CascadeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all).

```
class RequestDevice {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="STATUS", nullable=false)
    private DeviceStatusType deviceStatusType;
    ..
}
```

Above your code, When you persist `RequestDevice`, `EntityManager` assume the reference `DeviceStatusType` already exist in the datebase. Otherwise, you will get the error like your error status.
if would you like to persist together, try as below.

```
class RequestDevice {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) or @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    private DeviceStatusType deviceStatusType;
    ..
}
```

Comment: Thank you @CycDemo. But it is working fine when am doing in Java code. Its not working when i am using camel to do the job. And i already have data for DeviceStatusType, so i don't want to persist DeviceStatusType with RequestDevice.

Comment: Are you sure that you set "RequestDevice" in "DeviceStatusType" and "DeviceStatusType" in "RequestDevice"? in both scenarios... in any case i suggest you to remove the flush operation because isn't a good practices.

Comment: "DeviceStatusType" in "RequestDevice"... yeah am doing this. But not thh first one. Because DeviceStatusType already has the data. So i dont want to persist DeviceStatusType.