# Unable to get usage of CascadeTypes

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship, cascade, jpa-annotations

I have two domain classes. Below is the rough sketch of the classes.

**Company.java**

```
public class Company{

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval="true",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
    mappedBy="company")
    private List<Department> departments;

}
```

**Department.java**

```
public class Department{

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
   private Company company

}
```

[JPA @ManyToOne with CascadeType.ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all) says that The meaning of CascadeType.ALL is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations `(PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH)` to the relating entities.

**Test.java's main method**

```
//session started and transaction begin
Company company=new Company();
company.setName("Company");

Department department=new Department();
department.setName("Testing department");

department.setCompany(company);

session.save(department);

//transaction committed and session closed
```

It gives my Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: someValue
```

But when I use `CascadeType.ALL` on @ManyToOne annotation,it works fine, but not with `CascadeType.PERSIST`
So what should I use to make this example work without using `CascadeType.ALL` as ALL uses `(PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH)`. So which of following I should uses to get my work done instead of ALL and how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the CascadeType to `PERSIST` in `Department` entity so you have to use `session.persist(Object)` method instead of `save`.

So use this:

```
session.persist(department);
```

**Update:**

The `Company` entity has CascadeType set to `ALL` on `Department`. Also in a one-to-many relationship the Many side which is `Department` is the owner of the association.

So if you save the `Company` instead of `Department` the `CascadeType.ALL` is applicable. As Company is not the owner of the association, you have to add the department to your `Company` to maintain the bi-directional relationship. The code looks like this.

```
    List<Department> departments = new ArrayList<Department>();
    departments.add(department);
    company.setDepartments(departments);

    session.persist(company); // or you can also use save here.
```

If you do not maintain the relationship then `Department` will not be saved in database.

Comment: So my question is how CASCADE.ALL works without using persist method?

Comment: You have given another option. But save(department) works for CASCADE.ALL and not for CASCADE.PERSIST, this answer is not satisfactory??. In my question I have mention one link which says ALL is combination of MERGE,PERSIST,DETACH,REMOVE etc. Then which options to use instead of ALL as it works with ALL but not with PERSIST. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: looks like you are confused, `CASCADE.ALL` is provided between Company & Department. So it works for save(company) or persist(company) etc, where as `CASCADE.PERSIST` is provided between`Department` & `Company` so it works only if you do `session.persist(department)`, so what is missing here? it seems you are looking in opposite directions which is not correct.

Comment: So my question is ALL is present then which cascade types it use. as link says it uses one of the above types. I'm not confuse. Just wanted to know how to use. As ALL internally must be using any of the CASCADE types so what it use.

Comment: ok, now got your point, `ALL` means all operations, not like any single operation, means not `one of the above types.` . The link in your question tells the same thing --> `The meaning of CascadeType.ALL is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.`

Comment: I already said persist & save works in my answer, I clear on what else you are expecting.

Comment: ok, now I see your updated question. Based on my answer you can already guess what it should be. The answer is PERSIST and SAVE. As you are are using JPA, the answer is `PERSIST` as there is no `SAVE` option.

Comment: Correct answer is @ManyToOne(cascade={ CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }) which other person has given. There is no way to change persist() method according to my requirement. Thanks and I will upvote your answer as it could another solution.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, first try to understand what each operation will do, then you will know what type to select. `MERGE` is used if you try to load an object from session and at the same time you are creating another object with same id and wanted to merge it with what hibenate is maintaining in session. So unless you do such operation MERGE is not needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62262/discussion-between-shoaib-chikate-and-chaitanya).

Comment: `REMOVE`, if you try to delete the child if you want to remove the parent. So based on your requirement you can decide whether you want to have it or not. Same applies to `DETACH`

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62262/discussion-between-shoaib-chikate-and-chaitanya we can have chat

Comment: `REFRESH` it has a special meaning, it is not required for you. So based on this explanation you have to decide what is required for your mapping.

Comment: Sorry please, I cannot join for a chat now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mixing JPA annotations with Hibernate session interface.

If you are using Hibernate Session interface you should youse Hibernate annotations. That is:

```
  @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_OR_UPDATE)
  private Company company
```

If you choose to use JPA annotations you should use EntityManager interface and call

```
  entityManager.persist(departement);
```

instead of session.save().

My suggestion is to stick to the JPA interface and use EntityManager.

**UPDATE:**

I think the real problem is that you're trying to persist (or save) an unattached entity, the Departement, that is related to another unattached entity, the Company, in a One-to-many relationship. When it happens Hibernate must check if the Company is already present on the db, by merging (attaching) the Company entity. 
So if you want to insert in the DB a new record for Departement and another one for Company you must alternatively:

- call persist(company) before saving the departement, so that the Company entity is already merge and Hibernate doesn't need to merge it.

OR add CascadeType.MERGE to Company

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={ CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
private Company company
```

Comment: So my question is how CASCADE.ALL works without using persist method?

Comment: you can see whats my actual Question is. ALL means all operations, not like any single operation, means not one of the above types. . The link in my question tells the same thing --> The meaning of CascadeType.ALL is that the persistence will propagate (cascade) all EntityManager operations (PERSIST, REMOVE, REFRESH, MERGE, DETACH) to the relating entities.

Comment: You need at least @ManyToOne(cascade={ CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }). CascadeType.ALL includes both

Comment: Please include this in your answer. It works. And no need of calling persist(company). So please update that so I can accept this answer.

Comment: How MERGE and PERSIST works here in case of two unattached entity? Because I am not calling persist(company) hence Company still in Transient state.

Comment: yes, and when you call save(departement) (or persist(departement)) the company instance will be merged and thus attached, together with the departement. If a company with the same id already exists in the DB no new records will be created, or else a new record will be inserted.