# Delete an item from a list in a JPA entity

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to remove an item from a list in an Entity. I have this Entity :

```
@Entity
public class PairingCommit extends Model
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "commit")
    public List<CommitItem> items;
}
```

I do the following for removing an Item :

```
commit.items.remove(item);
commit.update();
```

But it doesn't remove the object from the database.
I suppose i missed something up...

EDIT : After some search, I'm not sure to use JPA... I'm working with Play framework 2 that use Ebean... But it seems that I have access to JPA annotation..

My first problem was that trying to directly delete the item like this :

```
CommitItem.byId(id).delete();
```

But it give a OptimisticLockException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have solved the problem of Optimistick Lock. It was that mysql failed to compare floating point number. I have passed to DECIMAL type and works fine now.
But I d'ont understand why the removing of list don't works.

Here an article on how Optimistick lock works : http://www.avaje.org/occ.html

Answer (score 0):

You should call EntityManager 's remove method on item.

```
EntityManager em;

item = em.merge(item); // Now item is attached
em.find(PairingCommit.class, [Pairing Commit PK]).items.remove(item);
em.remove(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all) The CascadeType annotation will propagate EntityManager operations to the linked entities. The way your code is currently set up, calling

```
entityManager.remove(pairingCommit);
```

would also delete all of the CommitItems that the PairingCommit is linked to, but

```
commit.items.remove(item);
```

is *not* an EntityManager operation, so nothing gets propagated.

You can get rid of the linked items directly with the EntityManager.

Comment: My problem is that if i directly delete my item, I get an OptimisticLockException...

Comment: That should only happen if another process has modified your item sometime between you loading it and saving it.

Comment: There might be a problem in your transaction design or how you access the databank (DAOs, domain stores, etc.)

Comment: there is no reason for another thread to access to the database at this time. I only do one request for testing so it should only have on thread.
And all the code is here... I use EBean/JPA to manage my database

Answer (score 0):

The [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says:

> It is particularly important to ensure that changes to the inverse
>   side of a relationship result in appropriate updates on the owning
>   side, so as to ensure the changes are not lost when they are
>   synchronized to the database.

So, you must remove from the owning side of relation:

```
commitItem.setCommit(null);
```

Comment: My problem is not here, I want to delete the CommitItem from the database, not update it.