# Spring Data: Deleting entites at the same time using different methods?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, asynchronous

Using `Spring data` is it possible to run 2 queries at the same time?

I ask as I have 2 query methods that I am calling to delete from the DB.

However I cannot run one before the other because it gives me the `"ORA-02292 integrity constraint child record found"` error.

Does the `@Async` annotation do what I am asking? If so, how do I use it?

Comment: You can research on how to do "cascade delete" in spring data

Comment: I have been searching for a clear example on this for ages, can you link one? thanks

Comment: You may go through this and some related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your description, you don't need run 2 queries at the same time. So:

Create 2 queries with 2 different methods and call them in order you want.

Use "cascade delete"