# java.lang.StackOverflowError when attempting to delete an entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

When attempting to delete an entity, a `StackOverflowError` occurs. The only time this happens is when I have a composite key containing 2 foreign key references. I created a minimal example below:

First object containing a `@OneToMany` collection:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Baz> baz;

    // Getters and setters omitted.
}
```

Second object containing an `@OneToMany` reference:

```
@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.bar", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Baz> baz;

    // Getters and setters omitted.
}
```

Object containing both of the objects above (`Foo` and `Bar`) as a composite key:

```
@Entity
public class Baz {

    @EmbeddedId
    private BazId id;

    // Getters and setters omitted.
}
```

And finally, the composite key class for `Baz`:

```
@Embeddable
public class BazId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8869241450494423817L;

    @ManyToOne
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne
    private Bar bar;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

When I perform the test below, I get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`:

```
// Spring Data JPA Repositories (extend CrudRepository)
@Autowired private FooRepository fooRepository;
@Autowired private BarRepository barRepository;
@Autowired private BazRepository bazRepository;

@Test
public void test() {
    final Foo foo = new Foo();
    fooRepository.save(foo);

    final Bar bar = new Bar();
    barRepository.save(bar);

    final Baz baz = new Baz(new BazId(foo, bar));
    bazRepository.save(baz);

    foo.getBaz().add(baz);
    bar.getBaz().add(baz);

    // These two deletes cause the StackOverflowError
    fooRepository.delete(foo);
    barRepository.delete(bar);
}
```

What I've tried:

- Overriding `equals(Object o)`, `toString()`, and `hashCode()`.

I'm not sure what else to try other than redoing my mapping entirely. I need the mapping to be setup this way as in my real project, I have a `User` following a `Business` so this needs to be a composite key between two entities. Why is this causing infinite recursion?

**EDIT**

Stack trace if it helps (part of it. Whole thing wont fit):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:131)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1929)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3956)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:632)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:687)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` right after `mappedBy = "id.bar"` ?

Comment: Stacktrace makes it look like you are having a recursive loading back and forth. Try lazy?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all

Comment: @MikeNakis Replace `Foo` with `User`, `Bar` with `Business` and `Baz` with `Follow`. If a `User` is deleted, then the `Follow` association should be deleted. If the `Business` is deleted, then the `Follow` association should be deleted as well. That's why both `Foo` and `Bar` are cascading.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek So the problem is, when I go to delete `Foo`, it tries to delete `Baz` as well? And inside `Baz`, there's `Bar`. So it checks `Bar`'s relationships and finds a `OneToMany` association on `Baz`. So it checks `Baz` and finds `Foo`, and then the cycle repeats until a `StackOverflowError` occurs? Or am I not understanding it properly?

Comment: @JakeMiller: I think this is what is happening... Probably the cascade is at fault.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek Check my other comment regarding my actual set up in my real project (User, Business and Follow). How would you suggest I set that up? Remove the cascading and simply delete everything manually?

Comment: This is not a valid use of an Embeddable. Check the JPA spec, section 11.1.17 `Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the `Baz` collection within `Foo` AND `Bar` causes infinite recursion when attempting to delete. Remove cascading on both of the collections and delete `Baz` relationships manually instead of cascading to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Tho Hibernate does claim support for directly modeling ManyToOne relationship mappings in the PK class, whether EmbeddedId or IdClass. I would suggest not designing to a specific persistence provider's implementation. The following example is designed to the JPA 2.0/2.1 specification and offers good portability.

#### Foo

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Baz> baz;
}
```

#### Bar

```
@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Baz> baz;
}
```

#### Baz

```
@Entity
public class Baz {
    @EmbeddedId
    private BazId id;

    @ManyToOne 
    @MapsId("fooid")
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne 
    @MapsId("barid")
    private Bar bar;
}
```

#### BazId

```
@Embeddable
public class BazId implements Serializable {

    private long fooid;

    private long barid;
}
```

Comment: It's supported in Hibernate. That's not the problem. But do you recommend I approach it this way in order to be JPA 2.0 compliant? Approaching it this way will allow me to switch ORM vendors without having to overhaul my mapping right?

Comment: I was not aware that Hibernate did in fact support this, but I reviewed the Hibernate doc and they do note that Hibernate supports directly modeling the ManyToOne in the PK class. I will update my answer to remove the spec quote since it does not apply for this provider. Tho, I do stand by my suggestion.