# Bi-directional OneToMany relation out of sync between DB and application

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, one-to-many

when running my spring boot application, using a debugger the objects in the application are different from the information in the database. The information in the db is correct - the application wrong. As far as I can say, the application objects are corrupted due to selects statements fired when I save objects. I assume this is a side effect of the dirty check of hibernate. But I leave this to your judgement.

The code where I have the problem deals with Requirements, which can be assigned to Terms, to model "when to do what". Term is abstract. Concrete classes are e.g. Release, Phase. Requirement is also abstract depending on the size, concrete classes can be e.g. Epic, UserStory. However, the getter and setter of assign and unassign Requirements to Terms is in the abstract classes. Requirements and Terms can exist independant from each other.

I have the following setup: Spring boot, MySql, JavaFX UI + Controller class, which is annotated with @Controller, a number of Entities, each annotated with @Entity. The controller uses autowired services, each annotated with @Service. The services use autowired repositories, each extending CrudRepository. So I am NOT using any EntityManager explicitly, but only use save(), findAll() and alike.

I followed the approach explained in https://www.sogehtsoftware.de/blog/post/javafx-persistence-teil-3-jpa-lazy-loading to model my OneToMany / ManyToOne relationship which looks like this

```
..

@Entity
@Inheritance
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Requirement implements Serializable {

    .. several fields ..

    @ManyToOne
    private Term term;

    .. constructors, getter and setter of other fields ..

    public Term getTerm() {
        return term;
    }

    public void setTerm(Term newTerm) {

        String txt = newTerm==null?"null":newTerm.debug();
        logger.debug(txt);

        if(term != null) {
            term.delRequirement(this);
        }
        this.term = newTerm;
    }
}
```

and

```
..

@Entity
@Inheritance
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class Term implements Serializable {

    .. several fields ..

    /*
    * see https://www.sogehtsoftware.de/blog/post/javafx-persistence-teil-3-jpa-lazy-loading
    */
    @Transient
    private List<Requirement> requirements;
    @Transient
    private ObservableList<Requirement> observableRequirements = FXCollections.observableArrayList();   // an observable mirror of field requirements

    .. constructors, getter and setter of other fields ..

    public ObservableList<Requirement> getObservableRequirements() {
        return observableRequirements;
    }

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="term", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Requirement> getRequirements() {
        return requirements;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")     // Used by JPA
    private void setRequirements(List<Requirement> requirements) {

        logger.debug(requirements.size() + " reqs to " + this.debug());

        this.requirements = requirements;
        observableRequirements.setAll(FXCollections.observableArrayList(requirements));
    }

    public void addRequirement(Requirement requirement) {

        logger.debug(requirement.debug() + " to " + this.debug());

        requirements.add(requirement);
        observableRequirements.add(requirement);
        requirement.setTerm(this);
    }

    public void delRequirement(Requirement requirement) {

        logger.debug(requirement.debug() + " from " + this.debug());

        if(requirements.contains(requirement)) {
            if(!requirements.remove(requirement)) {
                logger.error("Removal of requirement from list failed! Term: " + this.toString());
            }
            if(!observableRequirements.remove(requirement)) {
                logger.error("Removal of requirement from observable list failed! Term: " + this.toString());
            }

            requirement.setTerm(null);
        }
    }
}
```

I fill the application and database using CommandLineRunner at startup with some test data. That works perfect. When I unassign a Requirement from the Term and save, the database and the requirements List object of the Term are initially both correct. The code from the controller looks like this:

```
protected void unassignRequirement(Requirement requirement, Term term {

    logger.debug("Enter: " + requirement.debug() + "; " + term);

    if(term == null) {
        return;
    }

    ChronoUnit chronoUnit =  requirement.getDefaultEffortUnit();

    if(term != null) {
            term.delRequirement(requirement);
            chronoUnit = term.getDefaultTimeUnit();
    }

    logger.debug("Calling save on requirement");
    reqService.save(requirement);

    requirementsTreeView.refresh();  // show the requirement in a different color to indicate that it is assigned
    updateEffortInfo(assignedRequirementsListView.getItems(), chronoUnit);

    logger.debug("Leave: " + requirement.debug());

    // Interestingly, when I stop here for debugging requirement.getTerm() returns null as it should be
}
```

But immediatly thereafter, if I check the content of the requirement, getTerm() will return the previous Term assoziation as if it was never set to null.

Here is the trace (shortened due to space limitations) after the user clicked unassign button:

```
 DEBUG  PlanningPaneController.getSelectedAssignedRequirements:422: Enter getSelectedUnassignedRequirement 
DEBUG  PlanningPaneController.getSelectedTerm:429: Enter getSelectedTerm 
DEBUG  PlanningPaneController.unassignRequirement:359: Enter: 1@Epic: administrate the requirements; Term: first release; first release; null 
DEBUG  Term.delRequirement:283: 1@Epic: administrate the requirements; Term: first release from 1@Release: first release; 2 requirements; 5 children as root element 
DEBUG  PlanningPaneController$4.changed:264: Enter getAssignRequirementsChangeListener::changed: As a System Engineer, I want handle technical risks, such that to prioritize the development order 
DEBUG  Requirement.setTerm:336: null 
DEBUG  Term.delRequirement:283: 1@Epic: administrate the requirements; Term: first release from 1@Release: first release; 1 requirements; 5 children as root element 
DEBUG  PlanningPaneController.unassignRequirement:380: Calling save on requirement 
Hibernate: select epic0_.id as id2_2_0_, epic0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_0_, epic0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_0_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_1_1_, product0_.identifier as identifi2_1_1_, product0_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select term0_.id as id2_5_2_, term0_.begin as begin3_5_2_, term0_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_2_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select term0_.id as id2_5_2_, term0_.begin as begin3_5_2_, term0_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_2_, term0_.end as end5_5_2_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_14_5_0_, children0_.id as id2_5_0_, children0_.id as id2_5_1_, children0_.begin as begin3_5_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_14_5_0_, children0_.id as id2_5_0_, children0_.id as id2_5_1_, children0_.begin as begin3_5_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select requiremen0_.term_id as term_id11_2_0_, requiremen0_.id as id2_2_0_, requiremen0_.id as id2_2_1_, requiremen0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, ..  (cut)
.. several setRequirements of Terms ..
DEBUG  Term.setRequirements:264: 2 reqs to 1@Release: first release; 0 requirements; 5 children as root element 
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_1_, children0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_1_, children0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_1_, effortesti0_.best_case_estimate as best_cas2_0_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_1_, status0_.creation_time as creation2_3_1_, status0_.owner as owner3_3_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_1_, children0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_1_, effortesti0_.best_case_estimate as best_cas2_0_1_, .. (cut)
Hibernate: select status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_1_, status0_.creation_time as creation2_3_1_, status0_.owner as owner3_3_1_, status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_1_, status0_.state as state4_3_1_ from requirement_status status0_ where status0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_1_, children0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_1_, children0_.product_id as product_9_2_1_, children0_.team_id as team_id10_2_1_, children0_.term_id as term_id11_2_1_, children0_.req_what as req_what4_2_1_, children0_.req_when as req_when5_2_1_, children0_.req_who as req_who6_2_1_, children0_.req_why as req_why7_2_1_, children0_.dtype as dtype1_2_1_, product1_.id as id1_1_2_, product1_.identifier as identifi2_1_2_, product1_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_2_, product2_.id as id1_1_3_, product2_.identifier as identifi2_1_3_, product2_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_3_, team3_.id as id1_4_4_, team3_.capacity_per_day as capacity2_4_4_, team3_.identifier as identifi3_4_4_, term4_.id as id2_5_5_, term4_.begin as begin3_5_5_, term4_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_5_, term4_.end as end5_5_5_, term4_.goal as goal6_5_5_, term4_.identifier as identifi7_5_5_, term4_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_5_, term4_.my_state as my_state9_5_5_, term4_.my_type as my_type10_5_5_, term4_.owner as owner11_5_5_, term4_.parent_id as parent_14_5_5_, term4_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_5_, term4_.publishing_date as publish12_5_5_, term4_.successor_id as success16_5_5_, term4_.version as version13_5_5_, term4_.product_id as product17_5_5_, term4_.dtype as dtype1_5_5_, term5_.id as id2_5_6_, term5_.begin as begin3_5_6_, term5_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_6_, term5_.end as end5_5_6_, term5_.goal as goal6_5_6_, term5_.identifier as identifi7_5_6_, term5_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_6_, term5_.my_state as my_state9_5_6_, term5_.my_type as my_type10_5_6_, term5_.owner as owner11_5_6_, term5_.parent_id as parent_14_5_6_, term5_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_6_, term5_.publishing_date as publish12_5_6_, term5_.successor_id as success16_5_6_, term5_.version as version13_5_6_, term5_.product_id as product17_5_6_, term5_.dtype as dtype1_5_6_, term6_.id as id2_5_7_, term6_.begin as begin3_5_7_, term6_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_7_, term6_.end as end5_5_7_, term6_.goal as goal6_5_7_, term6_.identifier as identifi7_5_7_, term6_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_7_, term6_.my_state as my_state9_5_7_, term6_.my_type as my_type10_5_7_, term6_.owner as owner11_5_7_, term6_.parent_id as parent_14_5_7_, term6_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_7_, term6_.publishing_date as publish12_5_7_, term6_.successor_id as success16_5_7_, term6_.version as version13_5_7_, term6_.product_id as product17_5_7_, term6_.dtype as dtype1_5_7_, term7_.id as id2_5_8_, term7_.begin as begin3_5_8_, term7_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_8_, term7_.end as end5_5_8_, term7_.goal as goal6_5_8_, term7_.identifier as identifi7_5_8_, term7_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_8_, term7_.my_state as my_state9_5_8_, term7_.my_type as my_type10_5_8_, term7_.owner as owner11_5_8_, term7_.parent_id as parent_14_5_8_, term7_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_8_, term7_.publishing_date as publish12_5_8_, term7_.successor_id as success16_5_8_, term7_.version as version13_5_8_, term7_.product_id as product17_5_8_, term7_.dtype as dtype1_5_8_, product8_.id as id1_1_9_, product8_.identifier as identifi2_1_9_, product8_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_9_ from requirement children0_ left outer join product product1_ on children0_.product_id=product1_.id left outer join product product2_ on product1_.parent_id=product2_.id left outer join team team3_ on children0_.team_id=team3_.id left outer join term term4_ on children0_.term_id=term4_.id left outer join term term5_ on term4_.parent_id=term5_.id left outer join term term6_ on term4_.predecessor_id=term6_.id left outer join term term7_ on term4_.successor_id=term7_.id left outer join product product8_ on term4_.product_id=product8_.id where children0_.parent_id=?
Hibernate: select effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_1_, effortesti0_.best_case_estimate as best_cas2_0_1_, effortesti0_.creation_date as creation3_0_1_, effortesti0_.fraction_of_parent as fraction4_0_1_, effortesti0_.owner as owner5_0_1_, effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_1_, effortesti0_.realistic_case_estimate as realisti6_0_1_, effortesti0_.remaining_effort_estimate as remainin7_0_1_, effortesti0_.time_unit as time_uni8_0_1_, effortesti0_.worst_case_estimate as worst_ca9_0_1_ from effort_estimate effortesti0_ where effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_1_, status0_.creation_time as creation2_3_1_, status0_.owner as owner3_3_1_, status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_1_, status0_.state as state4_3_1_ from requirement_status status0_ where status0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_1_, effortesti0_.best_case_estimate as best_cas2_0_1_, effortesti0_.creation_date as creation3_0_1_, effortesti0_.fraction_of_parent as fraction4_0_1_, effortesti0_.owner as owner5_0_1_, effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_1_, effortesti0_.realistic_case_estimate as realisti6_0_1_, effortesti0_.remaining_effort_estimate as remainin7_0_1_, effortesti0_.time_unit as time_uni8_0_1_, effortesti0_.worst_case_estimate as worst_ca9_0_1_ from effort_estimate effortesti0_ where effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_1_, status0_.creation_time as creation2_3_1_, status0_.owner as owner3_3_1_, status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_1_, status0_.state as state4_3_1_ from requirement_status status0_ where status0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select requiremen0_.product_id as product_9_2_0_, requiremen0_.id as id2_2_0_, requiremen0_.id as id2_2_1_, requiremen0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, requiremen0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_1_, requiremen0_.product_id as product_9_2_1_, requiremen0_.team_id as team_id10_2_1_, requiremen0_.term_id as term_id11_2_1_, requiremen0_.req_what as req_what4_2_1_, requiremen0_.req_when as req_when5_2_1_, requiremen0_.req_who as req_who6_2_1_, requiremen0_.req_why as req_why7_2_1_, requiremen0_.dtype as dtype1_2_1_, requiremen1_.id as id2_2_2_, requiremen1_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_2_, requiremen1_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_2_, requiremen1_.product_id as product_9_2_2_, requiremen1_.team_id as team_id10_2_2_, requiremen1_.term_id as term_id11_2_2_, requiremen1_.req_what as req_what4_2_2_, requiremen1_.req_when as req_when5_2_2_, requiremen1_.req_who as req_who6_2_2_, requiremen1_.req_why as req_why7_2_2_, requiremen1_.dtype as dtype1_2_2_, team2_.id as id1_4_3_, team2_.capacity_per_day as capacity2_4_3_, team2_.identifier as identifi3_4_3_, term3_.id as id2_5_4_, term3_.begin as begin3_5_4_, term3_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_4_, term3_.end as end5_5_4_, term3_.goal as goal6_5_4_, term3_.identifier as identifi7_5_4_, term3_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_4_, term3_.my_state as my_state9_5_4_, term3_.my_type as my_type10_5_4_, term3_.owner as owner11_5_4_, term3_.parent_id as parent_14_5_4_, term3_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_4_, term3_.publishing_date as publish12_5_4_, term3_.successor_id as success16_5_4_, term3_.version as version13_5_4_, term3_.product_id as product17_5_4_, term3_.dtype as dtype1_5_4_ from requirement requiremen0_ left outer join requirement requiremen1_ on requiremen0_.parent_id=requiremen1_.id left outer join team team2_ on requiremen1_.team_id=team2_.id left outer join term term3_ on requiremen1_.term_id=term3_.id where requiremen0_.product_id=?
Hibernate: select children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_0_, children0_.id as id2_2_1_, children0_.default_effort_unit as default_3_2_1_, children0_.parent_id as parent_i8_2_1_, children0_.product_id as product_9_2_1_, children0_.team_id as team_id10_2_1_, children0_.term_id as term_id11_2_1_, children0_.req_what as req_what4_2_1_, children0_.req_when as req_when5_2_1_, children0_.req_who as req_who6_2_1_, children0_.req_why as req_why7_2_1_, children0_.dtype as dtype1_2_1_, product1_.id as id1_1_2_, product1_.identifier as identifi2_1_2_, product1_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_2_, product2_.id as id1_1_3_, product2_.identifier as identifi2_1_3_, product2_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_3_, team3_.id as id1_4_4_, team3_.capacity_per_day as capacity2_4_4_, team3_.identifier as identifi3_4_4_, term4_.id as id2_5_5_, term4_.begin as begin3_5_5_, term4_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_5_, term4_.end as end5_5_5_, term4_.goal as goal6_5_5_, term4_.identifier as identifi7_5_5_, term4_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_5_, term4_.my_state as my_state9_5_5_, term4_.my_type as my_type10_5_5_, term4_.owner as owner11_5_5_, term4_.parent_id as parent_14_5_5_, term4_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_5_, term4_.publishing_date as publish12_5_5_, term4_.successor_id as success16_5_5_, term4_.version as version13_5_5_, term4_.product_id as product17_5_5_, term4_.dtype as dtype1_5_5_, term5_.id as id2_5_6_, term5_.begin as begin3_5_6_, term5_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_6_, term5_.end as end5_5_6_, term5_.goal as goal6_5_6_, term5_.identifier as identifi7_5_6_, term5_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_6_, term5_.my_state as my_state9_5_6_, term5_.my_type as my_type10_5_6_, term5_.owner as owner11_5_6_, term5_.parent_id as parent_14_5_6_, term5_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_6_, term5_.publishing_date as publish12_5_6_, term5_.successor_id as success16_5_6_, term5_.version as version13_5_6_, term5_.product_id as product17_5_6_, term5_.dtype as dtype1_5_6_, term6_.id as id2_5_7_, term6_.begin as begin3_5_7_, term6_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_7_, term6_.end as end5_5_7_, term6_.goal as goal6_5_7_, term6_.identifier as identifi7_5_7_, term6_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_7_, term6_.my_state as my_state9_5_7_, term6_.my_type as my_type10_5_7_, term6_.owner as owner11_5_7_, term6_.parent_id as parent_14_5_7_, term6_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_7_, term6_.publishing_date as publish12_5_7_, term6_.successor_id as success16_5_7_, term6_.version as version13_5_7_, term6_.product_id as product17_5_7_, term6_.dtype as dtype1_5_7_, term7_.id as id2_5_8_, term7_.begin as begin3_5_8_, term7_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_8_, term7_.end as end5_5_8_, term7_.goal as goal6_5_8_, term7_.identifier as identifi7_5_8_, term7_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_8_, term7_.my_state as my_state9_5_8_, term7_.my_type as my_type10_5_8_, term7_.owner as owner11_5_8_, term7_.parent_id as parent_14_5_8_, term7_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_8_, term7_.publishing_date as publish12_5_8_, term7_.successor_id as success16_5_8_, term7_.version as version13_5_8_, term7_.product_id as product17_5_8_, term7_.dtype as dtype1_5_8_, product8_.id as id1_1_9_, product8_.identifier as identifi2_1_9_, product8_.parent_id as parent_i3_1_9_ from requirement children0_ left outer join product product1_ on children0_.product_id=product1_.id left outer join product product2_ on product1_.parent_id=product2_.id left outer join team team3_ on children0_.team_id=team3_.id left outer join term term4_ on children0_.term_id=term4_.id left outer join term term5_ on term4_.parent_id=term5_.id left outer join term term6_ on term4_.predecessor_id=term6_.id left outer join term term7_ on term4_.successor_id=term7_.id left outer join product product8_ on term4_.product_id=product8_.id where children0_.parent_id=?
Hibernate: select effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_0_, effortesti0_.id as id1_0_1_, effortesti0_.best_case_estimate as best_cas2_0_1_, effortesti0_.creation_date as creation3_0_1_, effortesti0_.fraction_of_parent as fraction4_0_1_, effortesti0_.owner as owner5_0_1_, effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id as parenta10_0_1_, effortesti0_.realistic_case_estimate as realisti6_0_1_, effortesti0_.remaining_effort_estimate as remainin7_0_1_, effortesti0_.time_unit as time_uni8_0_1_, effortesti0_.worst_case_estimate as worst_ca9_0_1_ from effort_estimate effortesti0_ where effortesti0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_0_, status0_.id as id1_3_1_, status0_.creation_time as creation2_3_1_, status0_.owner as owner3_3_1_, status0_.parental_requirement_id as parental5_3_1_, status0_.state as state4_3_1_ from requirement_status status0_ where status0_.parental_requirement_id=?
Hibernate: select releases0_.product_id as product17_5_0_, releases0_.id as id2_5_0_, releases0_.id as id2_5_1_, releases0_.begin as begin3_5_1_, releases0_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_1_, releases0_.end as end5_5_1_, releases0_.goal as goal6_5_1_, releases0_.identifier as identifi7_5_1_, releases0_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_1_, releases0_.my_state as my_state9_5_1_, releases0_.my_type as my_type10_5_1_, releases0_.owner as owner11_5_1_, releases0_.parent_id as parent_14_5_1_, releases0_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_1_, releases0_.publishing_date as publish12_5_1_, releases0_.successor_id as success16_5_1_, releases0_.version as version13_5_1_, releases0_.product_id as product17_5_1_, term1_.id as id2_5_2_, term1_.begin as begin3_5_2_, term1_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_2_, term1_.end as end5_5_2_, term1_.goal as goal6_5_2_, term1_.identifier as identifi7_5_2_, term1_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_2_, term1_.my_state as my_state9_5_2_, term1_.my_type as my_type10_5_2_, term1_.owner as owner11_5_2_, term1_.parent_id as parent_14_5_2_, term1_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_2_, term1_.publishing_date as publish12_5_2_, term1_.successor_id as success16_5_2_, term1_.version as version13_5_2_, term1_.product_id as product17_5_2_, term1_.dtype as dtype1_5_2_, term2_.id as id2_5_3_, term2_.begin as begin3_5_3_, term2_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_3_, term2_.end as end5_5_3_, term2_.goal as goal6_5_3_, term2_.identifier as identifi7_5_3_, term2_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_3_, term2_.my_state as my_state9_5_3_, term2_.my_type as my_type10_5_3_, term2_.owner as owner11_5_3_, term2_.parent_id as parent_14_5_3_, term2_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_3_, term2_.publishing_date as publish12_5_3_, term2_.successor_id as success16_5_3_, term2_.version as version13_5_3_, term2_.product_id as product17_5_3_, term2_.dtype as dtype1_5_3_, term3_.id as id2_5_4_, term3_.begin as begin3_5_4_, term3_.default_time_unit as default_4_5_4_, term3_.end as end5_5_4_, term3_.goal as goal6_5_4_, term3_.identifier as identifi7_5_4_, term3_.my_number as my_numbe8_5_4_, term3_.my_state as my_state9_5_4_, term3_.my_type as my_type10_5_4_, term3_.owner as owner11_5_4_, term3_.parent_id as parent_14_5_4_, term3_.predecessor_id as predece15_5_4_, term3_.publishing_date as publish12_5_4_, term3_.successor_id as success16_5_4_, term3_.version as version13_5_4_, term3_.product_id as product17_5_4_, term3_.dtype as dtype1_5_4_ from term releases0_ left outer join term term1_ on releases0_.parent_id=term1_.id left outer join term term2_ on term1_.predecessor_id=term2_.id left outer join term term3_ on term1_.successor_id=term3_.id where releases0_.product_id=?
Hibernate: update requirement set default_effort_unit=?, parent_id=?, product_id=?, team_id=?, term_id=?, req_what=?, req_when=?, req_who=?, req_why=? where id=?
DEBUG  PlanningPaneController.updateEffortInfo:279: Enter updateEffortInfo: 1 requirements; ChronoUnit: Years 
DEBUG  PlanningPaneController.unassignRequirement:386: Leave: 1@Epic: administrate the requirements; Term: null  <<< CORRECT !!

User selects Requirement from TreeView - no other interaction

DEBUG 05:32:25 PlanningPaneController$3.changed:234: Enter getRequirementSelectionChangeListener::changed: 1@Epic: administrate the requirements; Term: first release  <<< WRONG !!
DEBUG 05:32:25 PlanningPaneController.getSelectedTerm:429: Enter getSelectedTerm
```

Please let me know if you need additional information or code.

What do I have to do, to have also the correct objects in the application?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with the cascade rules of jpa. When persisting the requirement it may does not persist the change in term, so that after refresh the link is still there.

Consider the following options:

- check the cascade rules if one fits your needs: [JPA @ManyToOne with CascadeType.ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all)
- consider changing to an unidirectional data model so that persisting and updating is much easier