# Hibernate does not remove Parent oneToMany relationShip

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

It's been a couple of days since i blocked on the removal of a parent and child entity using cascade from JPA and HibernateProvider. I read a lot of about this subject but what i read does not work on my side.

1/ My parent UtilisateurEntity, using cascade, lazy and orphanRemoval, and the Child RoleEntity, using

```
@Entity(name = "UtilisateurEntity")
@Table(name = "utilisateur",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "login", columnNames = "login")})
@XmlRootElement
public class UtilisateurEntity implements Serializable {

    // skipped attributes for the post

    **@OneToMany( mappedBy = "utilisateur", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)**
    private List<RoleEntity> roles = new ArrayList();

    //skip Constructor and getters/setters

    public void addRole(RoleEntity roleEntity){
      roleEntity.setUtilisateurEntity(this);
      this.roles.add(roleEntity);
    }

    public void deleteRole(RoleEntity roleEntity){
       this.roles.remove(roleEntity);
       roleEntity.setUtilisateurEntity(null);
    }

    //skip equals and hashCode
}

@Entity(name = "RoleEntity")
@Table(name = "role",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "role_utilisateurId", columnNames = {"role", "utilisateurId"})
    })
@XmlRootElement
public class RoleEntity implements Serializable {

    // skipped attributes for the post

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "utilisateurId", nullable = false)
    private UtilisateurEntity utilisateur;

    //Skip Constructors, getters setters, equas and hashCode
}
```

2/ I use spring and annotation configuration for the businnes bean and xml configuration for infrastructure bean like (datasource, transaction, entitimanagerFactory, jpaVendorAdapter). 
I use JPA pour peristence data into MYSQL database and hibernate like the jpa provider.

3/ I use maven and my application is divided into several maven sub-module, one for service (business), one for dao, one for entity, one for batch, one for infrastructure (AOP, transaction, ...), one for webapp. Each sub-mode has its own spring configuration.
I use the Dto pattern, mean each sub-module manages her own object modele (entity for DAO sub-module, dto for Service sub-module). Selma mapper build conversion between both objects.

3/Service utilisateur use dao for create and delete utilisateur and own roles.

```
@Service("utilisateurService")
public class UtilisateurServiceImpl implements IUtilisateurService{
    @Autowired
    private IUtilisateurDao utilisateurDao;
    @Autowired
    private IUtilisateurMapper utilisateurMapper;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //skipped

    @Override
    public void delete(String login){

       UtilisateurEntity entity;

       entity = this.utilisateurDao.findByLogin(login);
       this.utilisateurDao.delete(entity);
    }
}

@Repository("utilisateurDao")
public class UtilisateurDaoImpl implements IUtilisateurDao
{

    ....

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity)
    {
        this.entityManager.remove(entity);
    }

    ....
}
```

PROBLEMS:
When i create or update UtilisateurEntity like this :
    this.utilisateurService.create(dto)
it's create my new UtilisateurEntity into Mysql DB. The function use mapper to convert from DTO to ENTITY and DAO persist into DB without problems.

But when i remove the parent Entity, so the UtilisateurEntity like this:
    this.utilisateurService.delete(dto);
this call show that the function find entity by login it is call correctly. The entity has been returned.
After that, the call of 
    utilisateurDao(entity);
does not give the error, but the entity Parent and Child, so UtilisateurEntity and her RoleEntity are not deleted into Mysql DB.

I thought the problem was the transaction spring configuration, but i do not see the mistake.

```
<tx:advice id="serviceTxAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceTxPointCut"
                  expression="execution(* com.hsmr.genealogie..*ServiceImpl.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="serviceTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceTxPointCut"/>
</aop:config>
```

Please Help

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/jpa-manytoone-with-cascadetype-all

Comment: Thanks! I already read this post and does what is written for the relation ship between Parent and Child entity. When i persist the parent, all childs are peristed also into DB. But it is not the same think for the remove wich does not remove parent and child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps, the issue was i dclared the wrong Dialect in my Hibernate configuration for MYSQL 5 DataBase.

```
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```