# Spring JPA ManyToOne deletion handle

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two POJOs, one is for **Post** which is below

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
    ...
}
```

and another one is for Category as below

```
@Entity(name = "category")
public class Category {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Post> post;
    ...
}
```

I have two crud repositories for each class. And here is my issue. `GET, POST, PUT` is working as expected. But for `DELETE` it is creating the issue. Suppose ***POST A*** has Category type C. When I am trying to delete ***POST A*** it is not only deleting ***POST A*** itself also deleting ***Category C*** and all Posts related to ***Category C***.

Please help :)

Comment: Please be more careful when using annotations or code that you have seen somewhere in general. Make sure that you first understand what you use. This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-cascadetype-all-for-a-manytoone-jpa-association

Comment: Thank you @EiriniGraonidou. will keep this in mind. The link you shared is really helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `CascadeType`, of the `Post` side. `CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.REMOVE`, so when you delete a post, the category to which that post belongs will be removed as well. Retain only `CascadeType.ALL` on the `Category` side and remove it from `Post`.

Comment: @SayantanBanerjee Try to upvote also when you find any solution helpful.