# Cascade type in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm a new to Spring boot.
I'd like to know which cascade type I have to use in this case.

I have an **Employee** class and a **Departement**.

Many Employees can work in a Departement (So i guess it's a **@ManyToOne Relation**) and a Department can have one or more Employees (so it's a **@OneToMany).

I want to perform some edits on the Employee class which have to be propagated to the other dependency.
BUT if I delete one employee, I can't delete an entire Departement, so I have to just delete the Employee.

```
@Entity
public class Department
{
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;
  @Id
  private String code;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String address;
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String website;
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String cellNumber;


  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
  private Set<Employee> emplpoyee;
  
  //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Here is the **Employee** Class

```
public class Employee
{
  @Id
  private String SSN;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String lastname;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String gender;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String role;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.???, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(
        name = "employee_works_in_dept",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_SSN")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "dept_code")}
)
private Department department;
}
```

What is that I have to replace with ??

I tried with CascadeType.ALL but it also deletes the Entire Department

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I don't think you need a separate join table if your **Employee** can only be a part of **one Department**.
If your employee can work on multiple departments then it is **Many to Many** relation.

When considering your question, you can simply remove your **CascadeType**. you don't need it in the **Employee** class.

If you need to delete all the employees under a **Department** when **Department** is deleted , then you can simply add your **CascadeType.ALL** on **Department** side.

There is a previous thread with better answer here.
[What is the meaning of the CascadeType.ALL for a @ManyToOne JPA association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-cascadetype-all-for-a-manytoone-jpa-association)

Comment: You might be correct! BTW if a department might be deleted, I'd also like to simply put a simple NULL value in the department field in the Employee