# Save parent enity contain child records list then auto delete child records in DB and not in child records list

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to config entities(options and options_values) to when save Option entity, then Options_values enitity list in Option entity also save records in DB and auto delete Options_values records in DB not exist Options_values enitity list?

this is erd
[image]
options_values enity
[image]
[options entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJN9W.png)

Comment: Welcome! I think what you are refering to is cascading. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027214/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-cascadetype-all-for-a-manytoone-jpa-association) out.

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20170164) for why.